# Problem with decorator

Tags: python, decorator

```
def my_decorator(func) :
    print "I am a ordinary function"
    def wrapper() :
        print "I am function returned by the decorator"
        func()
    return wrapper
def lazy_function() :
    print "zzzzzzzz"

functionDecorator=my_decorator(lazy_function)
```

I have in Debug IO

```
I am a ordinary function
```

I don't get it why there is any output. I understand why this line:

```
functionDecorator()
```

returns me:

```
I am function returned by the decorator
another___zzzzzzzz
```

But for the rest I think I miss something

Comment: You are calling `my_decorator()`, so it gets executed.  There is nothing special about this function -- it is executed just as any function you call is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you first call `my_decorator`, before it returns the the function `wrapper`, it will print your message.

Try calling `functionDecorator()` again, you won't get the output a second time because the function has already been decorated by `my_decorator`. Each time you call `my_decorator`, however, it will print your message, because it is a normal function call (that happens to also return a decorated function).

Also, see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax for alternative syntax for implementing decorators.

Answer (score 4):

Decorator is a normal function, that takes another function and returns some modified function.

When you call:

```
functionDecorator=my_decorator(lazy_function)
```

code inside your decorator is instantly executed and so print statement is executed, new function is created and returned. Then, when you run decorated function (which is simply a new function built inside a decorator), only internal print is executed and the external is not executed ever again. Is that clear?